# cURL not working to scrape this search engine. Any ideas?

Tags: database, web-scraping, screen-scraping, search-engine

I have been able to scrape sites successfully that are simply HTML.
I have not been able to scrape the results of query using this form.
This is an older database that my company owns.
I am trying to scrape and display results from it instead of playing
everything into an iframe.
I was using cURL, but it isn't working for this particular task.

Would I need to rebuild this form and add other code to it?  Please advise.  It would be great assistance

```
http://65.74.148.68:7777/pls/golf/golf.extsearch

http://65.74.148.68:7777/pls/golf/extresults?lcompany=&lcity=Chico&lstate=CA&lzip=&BR=&GC=&GS=&TY=&INV=&RE=&PA=&WK=&i_info=0&search=++Search++&scompany=on&saddress=on&sphone=on&uname=&pword=
```